# Contains without order

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I want to search a list of strings using a set of characters and want to find matches regardless of order. For example if my list contains

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "can", "rock", "bird" };
```

I want to be able to search using "irb" and have it return bird. I have to do this many times so I am looking for the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = "irb";
List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "can", "rock", "bird" };

var result = testList.Where(i => query.All(q => i.Contains(q)));
```

For each item in the `testList` test to see if it contains all the letters in `query`

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, you need to check each character of word in another list of word.

For that, you can do like this :

```
    // Checks whether all character in word is present in another word
    Func<string, string, bool> isContain = (s1, s2) =>
    {
        int matchingLength = 0;
        foreach (var c2 in s2.ToCharArray())
        {
            foreach (var c1 in s1.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (c1 == c2)
                    ++matchingLength;
            }
        }

        // if matched length is equal to word length given, it would be assumed as matched
        return s2.Length == matchingLength;
    };

    List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "can", "rock", "bird" };
    string name = "irb";
    var fileredList = testList.Where(x => isContain(x, name));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about matching duplicates than checking if all characters in a sequence you are searching for are contained in the word would do for predicate:

```
 "irb".Except("bird").Count() == 0
```

And whole condition:

```
  List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "can", "rock", "bird" };
  var search = "irb";
  var matches = testList.Where(word => !search.Except(word).Any());
```

Notes:

- you need to normalize all words to lowercase if you need mixed case letters to match.
- if performance of searching for different values is critical - convert search string to HashSet first and do except manually.
- if you need to match different values against same list many times - convert list of strings to list of HashSet and use `search.All(c => wordAsHashSet.Contains(c))` as condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to achieve this

```
List<string> testList = new List<string>() { "can", "rock", "bird" };
var lst = testList.Where(x => x.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("IRD")).ToList();
```

Make sure you also compare the cases using `ToUpper` and the `string` you want to compare also make it `UpperCase`

Comment: This will only find if the letters are in the same order as the appear in the search word. I would like to say type in or and bring back rock

Comment: I guess you have to search using pairs.

Comment: @jsomers89 Just one thing how the matching word will appear. I mean how to match words `or` or word can also appear like `rk` ?